# sscanf function does not read the format as required

Tags: c

Im trying to use sscanf function in C but its not reading the format is its required, I've readed the documentation of the function and followed the examples but its still not working out well for me thus i would like to have some advises..

```
int main() {

  long int id;
  float grade,age;
  char name[40],city[40],country[40],line[100]="388891477\tItzel\tGardner\t21\t6\tIran\tTehran";

  int read_items = sscanf(line,"%ld %*[\t] %[a-zA-Z -] %*[\t] %f %*[\t] %f %*[\t] %[a-zA-Z -] %*[\t] %[a-zA-Z -]",
        &id,name,&age,&grade,country,city);

  printf("readed line is: %ld %s %f %f %s %s. sscanf() read %d items\n",id,name,grade,age,country,city,read_items);

}
```

current output:

```
readed line is: 3888914775  0.000000 0.000000  @�'�. sscanf() read 1 items
```

expected output:

```
readed line is: 3888914775 Itzel Gardner  21.000000 26.000000 Iran Tehran. sscanf() read 6 items
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

question requirements was to add the tabs so if there was a space in the input it should return that this input is incorrect and shouldn't read it thats the main reason i added the tabs so it could only read inputs that have tabs in it , so for example if input between id and name was only 1 space it shouldn't read it.. sorry for confusing everyone

so in the line[100]="3888914775 Itzel Gardner 21 26 Iran Tehran";

input the sepration input between each one can only be tab nothing else( not one space or two.. )

CORRECT INPUT EXAMPLE:

```
line[100]="388891477\tItzel\tGardner\t21\t6\tIran\tTehran";
```

Comment: @user3121023 Well my homework requires me to do it for tabs thats why i added it  maby their automatic checks will not pass, It still doesnt fix the output though.

Comment: Indeed, if I remove all occurrences  `%*[\t]` it seems to come closer to working: `readed line is: 2147483647 Itzel Gardner asdas  26.000000 21.000000 Iran Tehran . sscanf() read 5 items`

Comment: @FredLarson Hmm i tested it now it may have fixed part of the problem, But the sscanf should've readed 6 items not 5 , it takes Iran and Tehran as a whole specifier which is not what i want it to be, since Iran should be the in the country specifier and Tehran in the city specifier thus makes it 6 items, This was the purpose of the tabs. anything am I missing?.

Comment: @FredLarson note that "asdas" has been removed from the post.

Comment: I believe "Iran Tehran" is getting read as the country, leaving nothing for the city. Since you have a space in your specifier character set, there's no reason for it to stop reading at the space.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, I saw that after I posted. But now my comment is too old to edit, and it doesn't really make a lot of difference anyway.

Comment: If the city (New York) or country (El Salvador) has two words, or the surname (Da Salva) then you can use `strtok` or `strsep` to break at the `tab` separaters.

Comment: Edited my post now to show misconfusion that everybody thought that removing the \t actually solves my problem , it doesnt because the whole point of adding them was to make the check work only on inputs that have tabs separators between each word, by example ID TAB NAME TAB AGE TAB GRADE TAB COUNTRY TAB CITY, so if it was ID SPACE NAME SPACE AGE SPACE  GRADE etc.. it shouldn't even read it since its invalid input, understand my problem now? now what i want it so to read such inputs with TABS but it doesn't do that with my code. thanks for understanding and contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your code has a few issues.

First, the `%*[\t]` specifiers are interfering and should not be necessary. A space between specifiers in `sscanf` will cause all whitespace to be consumed.

Second, the ID value you have may overflow a `long int`, so you may need to use `long long` instead with a `%lld` specifier.

Finally, there seems to be some confusion about whether spaces or tabs separate fields. Spaces are valid values for all your string fields, but also given between field. Your comments mention tabs, but I don't see any in your `line` string. If you use tabs to separate your fields things work much better, as the tab character is not part of your specifier sets.

Here is my update of your code correcting all the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  long long id;
  float grade,age;
  char name[40],city[40],country[40],line[100]="3888914775\tItzel Gardner\t21\t26\tIran\tTehran";

  int read_items = sscanf(line,"%lld %[a-zA-Z -] %f %f %[a-zA-Z -] %[a-zA-Z -]",
        &id,name,&age,&grade,country,city);

  printf("readed line is: %lld %s %f %f %s %s. sscanf() read %d items\n",id,name,grade,age,country,city,read_items);

}
```

Output:

```
readed line is: 3888914775 Itzel Gardner 26.000000 21.000000 Iran Tehran. sscanf() read 6 items
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post that my question requirements was to add the tabs so if there was a space in the input it should return that this input is incorrect and shouldn't read it thats the main reason i added the tabs so it could only read inputs that have tabs in it , so for example if input between id and name was only 1 space it shouldn't read it.. sorry for confusing everyone, i still couldn't manage to fix it with the tabs but i was able to fix it by your help without tabs.

Comment: This solution works for the valid input with tabs, But the problem is if i add spaces in the input it will also work which is not what supposed to happen, like 1 or 2 spaces between id and name will make it also read it thats why i want it to read inputs that are separated by TABS only so the input: id space name space age etc.. wont work but the input id tab name tab age etc.. will only work, hope you understand my problem now thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {

  long int id;
  float grade,age;
  char name[40],city[40],country[40],line[100]="3888914775 Itzel Gardner 21 26 Iran Tehran";

  int read_items = sscanf(line,"%ld %[a-zA-Z- ] %f %f %[a-zA-Z-] %[a-zA-Z-]",
        &id,name,&age,&grade,country,city);

printf("readed line is: %ld %s %f %f %s %s. sscanf() read %d items\n",id,name,grade,age,country,city,read_items);

}
```

While removing `%*[\t]` from sscanf, your program will works fine. And also you don't want to change your datatype from float into int. Hope it will helps : )

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post that my question requirements was to add the tabs so if there was a space in the input it should return that this input is incorrect and shouldn't read it thats the main reason i added the tabs so it could only read inputs that have tabs in it , so for example if input between id and name was only 1 space it shouldn't read it.. sorry for confusing everyone, i still couldn't manage to fix it with the tabs but i was able to fix it by your help without tabs

Answer (score 1):

Use *string literal* concatenation to help clearly solve this.

To scan, and not save, a `'\t'` and only 1, use `"%*1[\t]"`.

Scan safely - use width limits when saving strings.  E.g `"%39[^\t]"`

Untested code:

```
#define FTAB "%*1[\t]"  
#define FID  FTAB "%ld"  
#define FTXT FTAB "%39[^\t]"
#define FNUM FTAB "%f"

long int id;
float grade,age;
char name[40],city[40],country[40];
char line[100]="388891477\tItzel\tGardner\t21\t6\tIran\tTehran";

int read_items = sscanf(line, FID FTXT FNUM FNUM FTXT FTXT,
    &id, name, &age, &grade, country, city);

printf("read %d items\n", read_items);
if (read_itmes == 6) {
  printf("readed line is: %ld %s %f %f %s %s\n", 
      id, name, grade, age, country, city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are writing your name with space . Because of that , it will be consider as a next input and accepted into next datatype which is in your code as ::

> In char array line , **Itzel Gardner** this is have space between each
>   other.

- you don't need to give **[A -Z a-z]** for storing string into char array , you just use **%s** for that .

> in sscanf , you should use %s instead of [A -Z a-z] .
>   - You don't need to give "\t" in in sscanf func.

this code has a solution

```
int main() 
{

        long int id;
        float grade,age;
        char name[40],city[40],country[40],line[100]="3888914775 Itzel_Gardean 21 26 Iran Tehran";

        int read_items = sscanf(line,"%ld %s %f %f  %s %s",&id,name,&age,&grade,country,city);

        printf("readed line is: %ld %s %f %f %s %s. sscanf() read %d items\n",id,name,grade,age,country,city,read_items);

}
```

Comment: Please read up about buffer overflows - i.e %s specifier should be qualified with the maximum size

Comment: If i dont use that then i can put any special char in the input as a name and it will still read it which is something that I shouldn't do in my homework, And i give it the \t in the sscanf func in order to make sure i recieved correct input which can only seprate the id , name , age, grade,country,city by tabs.

Comment: `%s` cannot be used to read strings with spaces in them, though.